# python, re.search / re.split for phrases which looks like a title, i.e. starting with an uppper case

Tags: python, regex, ignore-case

I have a list of phrases (input by user) I'd like to locate them in a text file, for examples:

```
    titles = ['Blue Team', 'Final Match', 'Best Player',] 
    text = 'In today Final match, The Best player is Joe from the Blue Team and the second best player is Jack from the Red team.'
```

1./ I can find all the occurrences of these phrases like so

```
    titre = re.compile(r'(?P<title>%s)' % '|'.join(titles), re.M)
    list = [ t for t in titre.split(text) if titre.search(t) ]
```

(For simplicity, I am assuming a perfect spacing.)

2./ I can also find variants of these phrases e.g. 'Blue team', final Match', 'best player' ... using re.I, if they ever appear in the text.

But I want to restrict to finding only variants of the input phrases with their first letter upper-cased e.g. 'Blue team' in the text, regardless how they were entered as input, e.g. 'bluE tEAm'.

Is it possible to write something to "block" the re.I flag for a portion of a phrase? In pseudo code I imagine generate something like '[B]lue Team|[F]inal Match'.

Note: My primary goal is not, for example, calculating frequency of the input phrases in the text but extracting and analyzing the text fragments between or around them.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `re.I` and modify the list-comp to:

```
l = [ t for t in titre.split(text) if titre.search(t) and t[0].isupper() ]
```

Comment: I should have added that I actually want to generate the regex 'titre' and use it to futher analyze the context surrounding/between the phrases.

Answer (score 1):

I think regular expressions won't let you specify just a region where the ignore case flag is applicable. However, you can generate a new version of the text in which all the characters have been lower cased, but the first one for every word:

```
new_text = ' '.join([word[0] + word[1:].lower() for word in text.split()])
```

This way, a regular expression without the ignore flag will match taking into account the casing only for the first character of each word.

Comment: Ugh. Use the batteries: `text.title()`.

Comment: @jcollado: Thanks! I've search around a bit and suspect it cant be done with one or two regexes. This would work for the context analysis. It would require another step to reconstruct the original text fragments between the matching phrases. But those fragments can be located easily based on their lengths.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for your comment. What I wanted to do is preserve the case of the first letter, but with `title` the first letter would be upcased. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying the input so that it is in the correct case before you use it in the regular expression?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Ideally these user-entered phrases should appear in the text as titles (either The 'Blue Team' or THE 'BLUE TEAM'), but sometimes in the text only the starting word has first letter capitalised. If it is not, I can safely ignore the phrase.